# stack protector enabled but compliler support broken

Tags: linux, azure, virtual-machine

We are trying to install asterisk call center solution on Azure VM platform but after unable to install the Dahdi-linux-complete setup file . It display below error

stack protector enabled but compliler support broken 
Config_x86_x32 enabled but no binutils support
cannot use config_cc_stackprotector_strong

screenshot:

[image]

Request for your help.

Regards,

Sohan Singh:

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with Azure. It just happens the distro you're on does not have GCC installed. Install with

```sh
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

or whatever the `yum` equivalent is for RedHats.

Answer (score 0):

EvilSnobu is right, according to the error message, you should install gcc first.
If you sure you have gcc, and the still can't use command make, you should check your /etc/environment, here are similar case, please refer to the [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/428220/cant-run-make-gcc-command-not-found).